# Rails: How to cancel current statements in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 with jRuby for a project. and I regularly use `rails console` for testing my classes and API, where somehow I experience one problem.
when I am working in the Rails console, if I mistakenly input some multi-line commands, is there a way to cancel it somewhere in the middle?

e.g.:

```
>> [1,2,3,4].inject(1){
?>
```

All I found is it will be expecting me to finish the whole completed statement, but all I wanna do is to cancel all current statements.

I've tried Ctrl+C, but it didn't work  for me.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Larry Thanks for that, but I did try so, still doesn't work.

Comment: try Ctrl+D I think it should work

Comment: @abhas nope, abhas. That only gets me to quit to the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the prompt, you can use the following command to control the irb session.

```
conf.ignore_sigint= true/false
```

This specifies the behavior of ^C (control-c). If false, ^C will quit irb. If true, ^C during input will cancel input and return to the top level; during execution, ^C will abort the current operation.

On the underside, rails console uses IRB. Also see:

```
http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/irb.html
```

### Edit

`rubycentral.com` link is dead.